# Why are my young tomato plant's leaves drooping and curling inward?

Tags: tomatoes

I bought this Mountain Magic plant 3 days ago. The woman at the garden store told me to wait about a week to let the ground warm up before planting. So I gave it still in the pot near where it will eventually be planted. It looked fine 3 days ago but now the branches are all limp and the leaves are curling.[image]

Comment: Did you acclimatise it first? It looks stressed from lack of water possibly due to lack of hardening.

Comment: It was outdoors at the nursery so I didn't think it would need hardening.

Comment: But probably not in full sun.

Comment: How dry/wet is the soil?

Comment: Unless it's caused by a virus, leaf curl usually remedies itself with proper care. What where the day and night temps where you had the plant? Did you water it at all while waiting to palnt? If so how much and how often did you water it? Did you fertilize it at all? One of the most common reasons for leaf curl is over watering.  See http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/hot_topics/2008/05tomato_leaf_roll.html

Comment: I brought it inside and watered it, and it made a full recovery within an hour or so. The soil was dry but I didn't think it would get that dry since it rained the previous day. I think I will go ahead and get it planted today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would plant the tomato. It seems a big plant (a lot of leaves) for a small vase. Probably it needs more water and fertilizers. But it will recover. On worse case, you will have a delay of a week in harvesting tomatoes.